# Scroll to items on keyboard input of very long dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a really long list of countries which I made into a dropdown menu that has the scroll, so you can scroll through them. It looks something likes this:

https://codepen.io/Karadjordje/pen/MEBjRY

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu scroll-menu" role="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        A
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        B
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        C
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        D
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        E
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        F
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to make some sort of search with this dropdown. I have no input field for search by design I was given, so I need to make it differently.

The desired functionality is that I should be able to use the keyboard to scroll to countries, let's say I press key "M" on my keyboard it scroll to countries which start with the letter "M", if I press "A" it should scroll back to countries starting with letter "A". Is there a way to achieve this and how should I approach this problem?

EDIT: Updated codepen with newest idea for solution

Comment: it's possible, but tricky and frankly overcomplicated. A `<select>` element would be vastly easier, less prone to errors and more compatible across devices.

Comment: This may be kickstart for you with basic approach https://codepen.io/obceylan/pen/KXeeGa

Comment: May this help: https://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone said in comments doing this is a bit tricky and complicated, but with that said I made a lot of progress. It's far from polished product, I'm pretty sure there are still some cases which I haven't covered, but for anyone else who might need this I think this will be strong foundation.

You can see it LIVE here: https://codepen.io/Karadjordje/pen/MEBjRY?editors=1010 
Here is the JS code:

```
$(function() {

    $('.dropdown').each(function() {
        var val = '';
        var $dropdown = $(this);
        var $list = $dropdown.find('ul');
        $dropdown.on('show.bs.dropdown', function() {
            $(document.body).on('keyup', typing);
            $list.find('a').css({ background: 'transparent' });
        });

        $dropdown.on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
            $(document.body).off('keyup', typing);
            val = '';
            $list.find('a').css({ background: 'transparent' });
        });

        function typing(e, alreadyChecked) { // we use alreadyChecked to break out of typing
            $list.find('a').css({ background: 'transparent' });
            if (e.keyCode === 8 && val.length > 1) { // This part allows backspace to delete previous characters entered
                val = val.split('').splice(0, val.length - 1).join('');
            } else if (e.key && e.key.length === 1) { // e.key.length === 1 this was adeed because of buttons like tab,alt,backspace etc. because they create infinite loop and exceed threads
                val += e.key.toLowerCase();
            } else {
                return;
            }
            console.log(e);
            if (val.length === 0) {
                return;
            }
            var els = $list.find('a').get().filter(function(node) {
                return $(node).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) === 0;
            });
            if (!els || els.length === 0) {
                val = '';
                if (alreadyChecked) {
                    typing(e, true);
                }
                return;
            }
            var scrollTop = $list[0].scrollTop;
            $list[0].scrollTop = scrollTop + $(els[0]).position().top - $(els[0]).height();
            $(els).css({ background: 'rgba(255, 171, 0, 0.3)' });
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery plugin that makes this functionality success could you please refer
the below url and consider this as a reference:

Reference url: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Go for standard select option